# Arch Linux: I get 500 error when trying to open PHP file

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd, php

I get the `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)` error with Chrome when trying to open a simple PHP file.

I have installed Apache and PHP correctly as instructed in [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP). Including the [PHP specific part](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LAMP#PHP) of it.

I get this error when I try going to the URL `http://localhost/~eduan/php_info.php`, I  made sure and this file has correct syntax and everything, here's it's contents:

```
<?php
php_info();
?>
```

It contains nothing else and nothing less.

I also have a test install of Statamic under `http://localhost/~eduan/statamic`, and that works and doesn't. It loads correctly, but all the styles and stuff of it is missing, meaning (from what I understand) that it couldn't load the theme which is done with PHP if I'm not mistaken.

That's all, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The [real command](http://php.net/manual/function.phpinfo.php) is `phpinfo()` (without the underscore).

Comment: Oops. OK that fixes that. What about the Statamic part of it though?

Comment: I don't know what statamic is. A bare style is usually the result of a CSS stylesheet not loaded: 87% of times this is due to a misconfiguration in the web application (AKA statamic). In any case it is not PHP related.

Comment: @ntd You'd be surprised. I've seen at least one "custom" CRM job that used php to generate CSS. Don't ask me for details, I worked long and hard to repress them...

Comment: @Shadur Oh yeah, I have also used PHP for generating dynamic images. If you have full access to the webserver configuration you can use PHP for generating pretty much anything served.

Answer (score 2):

Check your most error log, it is probably located in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/httpd/error.log` (or similar). It'll probably point you to the problem that @Eduan describes in the other answer.

It is good practice to always check the error logs first, there often is valuable information in them.